# Are the states of different keys shared in the Flink window operator?

Tags: window, key, state, apache-flink

For example, a windowOperator has 10 parallelisms, and there are 1000 different keys, then each parallelism will process 100 keys, are these 100 keys'states shared or isolated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, throughout Flink the state for different keys is isolated. This is done deliberately, so that the state can be resharded when rescaling the cluster.

In a `KeyedProcessFunction`, or in a `ProcessWindowFunction` for a keyed window, whenever you access or update state, there is a key implicitly in context. In the case of a `KeyedProcessFunction` this is key for the event or timer being processed; in the case of a `ProcessWindowFunction` it's the key associated with the events in the iterable provided. Any state accesses or updates performed will be scoped to that one key. There is no way to access or modify the state associated with other keys.

Comment: If i define a ValueStateDescriptor in ProcessWindowFunction(for example: private final ValueStateDescriptor<String> triggerTypeDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("triggerType", StringSerializer.INSTANCE);), and in process method,  i use "context.globalState().getState()" to accesss the state, the state is scoped to the key of current window ? If i update the state, i just update the state of the key of current window? the state with the same statedescriptor of other keys are not updated?

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit carried away explaining the corner cases, and didn't clearly respond to your actual question. I've updated my answer, but yes, you are only operating on the state of the key for the current window, and the state for other keys is not affected.